# How to use as_tbl_graph() with group_by()?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidygraph

this is a follow-up question to a recent [issue on calculating graph depth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48063592/mutate-value-by-using-a-value-from-a-different-row-in-a-tibble) I encountered. This involves tidyverse and tidygraph. After reading into tidygraph I felt I'd give it a proper try but I encountered a new problem in my workflow.

When working with the `group_by()` verb from **dplyr** to create a graph for each group, the `guess_df_type()` function in `as_tbl_graph()` from **tidygraph** does not what I'm looking for but I can't find a way to set the `from` and `to` value as intended. Here's a reproducible example:

```
library(tidygraph)
library(tidyverse)

tmp <- tibble(
  id_head = as.integer(c(4,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5)),
  id_sec  = as.integer(c(1,1,1,2,2,2,1,1,2,2)),
  token   = as.integer(c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,1,2)),
  head    = as.integer(c(2,2,2,1,1,2,2,2,2,2)),
  root    = as.integer(c(2,2,2,1,1,1,2,2,2,2))
) 
tmp %>%
  group_by(id_head, id_sec) %>% 
  as_tbl_graph()
```

The result to this is:

```
# A tbl_graph: 4 nodes and 10 edges
#
# An undirected multigraph with 1 component
#
# Node Data: 4 x 1 (active)
   name
  <chr>
1     4
2     5
3     1
4     2
#
# Edge Data: 10 x 5
   from    to token  head  root
  <int> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     3     1     2     2
2     1     3     2     2     2
3     1     3     3     2     2
# ... with 7 more rows
```

The nodes are not taken from the token column but from both `id_head` and `id_sec`.

After looking further into it I renamed `token` and `head` to `from` and `to` and this at least solves the first issue:

```
tmp %>% 
  rename(
    from = token,
    to = head
  ) %>% 
  as_tbl_graph(directed = FALSE)
```

Resulting:

```
# A tbl_graph: 3 nodes and 10 edges
#
# An undirected multigraph with 1 component
#
# Node Data: 3 x 1 (active)
   name
  <chr>
1     1
2     2
3     3
#
# Edge Data: 10 x 5
   from    to id_head id_sec  root
  <int> <int>   <int>  <int> <int>
1     1     2       4      1     2
2     2     2       4      1     2
3     2     3       4      1     2
# ... with 7 more rows
```

Let me further formulate the issue I'm having. When I try to use group_by(id_head,id_sec) inside the graph, the result is an error:

```
tmp %>% 
  as_tbl_graph() %>%
  group_by(id_head, id_sec)
```

> Error in grouped_df_impl(data, unname(vars), drop) :
>
> Column `id_head` is unknown

So either way, I do not understand how to use group_by with tidygraph. Any help is very much appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Also, sorry for using igraph as a tag, it should be tidygraph but that does not exist yet. tidygraph is build upon igraph and the tidyverse tho.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first question I’m a bit unsure how your data.frame should be parsed into a graph - tidygraph contains documentation about all the graph representations it understands and I suggest you consult this.

For the second question - it is simply a matter of nodes being active while the edges contains the variable you want to group on. Simply activate the edges prior to grouping...

```
tmp %>% 
  rename(
    from = token,
    to = head
  ) %>%
  as_tbl_graph() %>%
  activate(edges) %>%
  group_by(id_head, id_sec)
```

Comment: Regarding the first part: The data is a mockup of text data and both `token` and `head` represent the relationships of tokens towards each other in sentences (`id_sub`) within messages (`id_head`) as dependency trees.

Comment: So its sort of a linked list?

Comment: You could probably work on it similar to a linked list but I'm not sure if that helps understanding it. [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_grammar#Representing_dependencies)'s a better example how dependency trees in NLP may look like. In my case all tokens refer over at least one edge to the root token.

Comment: There is no build in support for this graph representation. If you pass in a single data.frame to `as_tbl_graph` it will expect it to be an edgelist, but yours is a nodelist with parent/child recorded as variables. I would suggest you extract the edge information into a separate data frame and just do `tbl_graph(nodes, edges)`